# Why is extending a template in Flask breaking the rest of the code?

Tags: python, html, templates, inheritance, flask

I'm learning Flask and this is the file structure of my first project:

[image: file structure]

**This is my app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from data import Articles

app = Flask(__name__)

Articles = Articles()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

@app.route('/contact')
def contact():
    return render_template('contact.html')

@app.route('/articles')
def articles():
    return render_template('articles.html', articles = Articles)

@app.route('/article/<string:id>/')
def article(id):
    return render_template('article.html', id=id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**This is my layout.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    {% block head %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Learning Flask - App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% endblock head %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'components/_navbar.html' %}
    <div class='container'>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**This is my home.html which is the only page working properly:**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
      <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image: home.html]

***This is my contact.html which doesn't show anything after the navigation bar, same problem with rest of the templates:***

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}


      <h1>WHY THE HELL DOESNT THIS SHOW UP!!</h1>


{% endblock %}
```

[image: contact.html]

Comment: As silly as this sounds can you make sure you saved all your files then restart your server and see if the issue still persists.

Comment: I have done that, multiple times in fact.

Comment: just wondering if this isn't some css issue. Does it show if you add class="display-3" to this line <h1>WHY THE HELL DOESNT THIS SHOW UP!!</h1>

Comment: Have you checked your page DOM through in-browser developer tools? Is code you are looking for in there? Also, it may be a CSS code as @gittert said or your JS code that modifies your page so blocks you want to see are hidden/deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, changing the navbar HTML fixed the problem. Don't know what exactly caused the issue but it was probably a matter of conflicting CSS.